# How to Create Time Table using GridView in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am looking to make a Time Table in C#. Please take a look at this image URL.

http://oi45.tinypic.com/25knc79.jpg

The Time Table should generate dynamically based on the given input by the user.

User should enter two input values, First one,'Lunch after which period' and 'No of periods' in a day.

If the value of Lunch after which period will be 2, the 'Break' should appear after second column.

The No of period determines the No of columns of the Time Table.

Based on user's input,the Time Table should generate. Please let me know, How and what to do this ?

Please guide me to proceed further.

Comment: it would be time consuming and less effective.. why don't try to find time line controls on asp.net?

Comment: @HichemC I didnt have experience with Time line controls before.

Comment: stackoverflow is problem problem-resolution approach not open question answer. you should've given chance to google to help you out

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I prefer to use jquery timetable for that or I create my own html table if it's specific. Check links. 
http://www.triballabs.net/2012/09/jquery-html-timetable-layout/ 
http://zarjay.net/2010/03/09/using-jquery-to-make-a-simple-scheduler-app/
http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/dd/dnd3.php